# negative margin with jquery css

Tags: jquery, css

Sure this question it´s very stupid, and i think it´s stupid, but i don´t know why don´t show me negative values in this jquery function for css, i need send -15% as margin-left and don´t works, if i put inside funtion this value works, but sending across function no, i don´t understand this :

```
function win(top,width,marginizq)
{
jQuery("#win_background").show(1000);
jQuery("#win_loader").css("margin-top",""+top);
jQuery("#win_loader").css("width",""+width);
jQuery("#win_loader").css("margin-left",""+marginizq);
}



<script>
win("200","30%","-15%");
</script>
```

All works fine but don´t get works when put negative -15%, if i put inside function as default yes

Why don´t works this ? i understand value must send negative or no, right ?

This it´s my question, thank´s

Comment: Can you add html code as well

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to be working just fine, although there is a small typo in the `margin-top` part where you should add a unit definition (`px`,`%` etc.). Also, you don't have to add the quotation marks before the variables when adding the css.

I.e. `.css("margin-top",""+top)` can be written as `.css("margin-top", top)`.

See that it works fine here (with corrected typo):

```js
function win(top,width,marginizq)
{
jQuery("#win_loader").css("margin-top", top);
jQuery("#win_loader").css("width", width);
jQuery("#win_loader").css("margin-left", marginizq);
}

win("200px","30%","-15%");
```

```css
#win_loader{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="win_loader">

</div>
```